# Is there a closed form solution to the parallel DGLAP evolution equation

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

The parallel DGLAP evolution equation is given by

$$t\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha_s(t)}{2\pi} \int_x^1 \frac{d\hat{x}}{\hat{x}} P_{qq}(\hat{x})f\left(\frac{x}{\hat{x}},t\right)$$

where

$$P_{qq}(x) = \frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)_+}-\frac{3}{2}\delta(1-x)$$

the $+$ represents the 'plus distribution' given by

$$\int_x^1 dx \frac{f(x)}{(1-x)_+} = \int_x^1 dx \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{1-x}-f(1)\int_0^x dx \frac{1}{1-x}$$.

$\alpha_s(t)$ is the strong coupling which is some smooth function of $t$ with known behavior. We have also the initial condition

$$f(x,t_0) = \mathcal{N} x^{\alpha}(1-x)^{\beta}$$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is a constant and $\alpha>0$, $\beta>0$

---

Attempt:

Calculation is simplified in Mellin space, ie

$$\tilde{f}(s,t) = \int_0^1 x^{s-1} f(x,t)$$

The differential equation becomes

$$\frac{\partial \tilde{f}(s,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha_s(t)}{2\pi t} \tilde{P}_{qq}(s)\tilde{f}\left(s,t\right)$$

Where $P_{qq}(s) = C_F \left[-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{N(N+1)}-2\sum_{k = 2}^N \dfrac{1}{k} \right]$ and $\tilde{f}(s,t_i) = \mathcal{N}\dfrac{\Gamma (\beta+1) \Gamma (s+\alpha )}{\Gamma (s+\alpha
   +\beta +1)}$

Have now 
$$\tilde{f}(s,t_f) = \tilde{f}(s,t_i) \exp\left\{\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\frac{dt}{t}\frac{\alpha_s(t)}{2\pi}\tilde{P}_{qq}(s) \right \}$$

Now one needs only to invert the Mellin transformation.

$$f(x,t_f) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} ds x^{-s} \tilde{f}(s,t_f)$$

Here $c$ is a constant that must be larger than $0$. This integration can be done numerically however the essential singularities presented by $P_{qq}(s)$ prevent me from using the residue theorem to obtain an expression for $f(x,t_f)$.